# How to open app links in flutter webview?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, I use the flutter [webview plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) to launch a url like:

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(url)
```

or

```
WebviewScaffold(
  url: url,
  appBar: new AppBar(title: Text(title), actions: [
    new IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
      onPressed: () => Share.share(url),
    )
  ]),
  withZoom: true,
  withLocalStorage: true,
  withJavascript: true,
);
```

However, if any links inside the opened web page is an app link, like: *fb://profile*, I will get net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

In android, I found the solution is to override shouldOverrideUrlLoading as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51806364/3321334), but what should I do in flutter?

Comment: could you put your code  ?

Answer (score 20):

You can use **webview_flutter** in pub.dev Packages

```
WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://my.url.com',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request)
        {
          if (request.url.startsWith('https://my.redirect.url.com'))
          {
            print('blocking navigation to $request}');
            _launchURL('https://my.redirect.url.com');
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }

          print('allowing navigation to $request');
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      )
```

And you can launch url with **url_launcher** in pub.dev Packages

```
_launchURL(String url) async {
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}}
```

Comment: I'm using the same code to allow mailto scheme in flutter webview (https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter). But it is throwing errors and I am unable to build the apk file.

Comment: Error: Not a constant expression.
                  if (request.url.contains("mailto:")) {
                      ^^^^^^^
Error: Method invocation is not a constant expression.
                  if (request.url.contains("mailto:")) {
                                  ^^^^^^^^
Error: Method invocation is not a constant expression.
                    launch(request.url);
                    ^^^^^^
Error: Not a constant expression.
                navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request)  {
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: I have posted this on stack as well. - Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65880593/how-to-allow-mailto-schemes-in-webview-flutter

Comment: This answer is deprecated now and removed from the package as well.\

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can achieve what you need using this plugin :  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_web_view

Listen for your redirects:

```
  flutterWebView.listenForRedirect("fb://profile", true);
```

Get the value using :

```
flutterWebView.onRedirect.listen((url) {
   flutterWebView.dismiss();
    //now you have the url
 });
```

After you have the url you can use this package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher

Comment: That plugin has a lot of issues, e.g. gradle file missing dependencies to kotlin, AndroidManifest file missing declaration of the activity, etc. I have emailed the developer to see if he still maintains it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution for the `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` Error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707918/webview-showing-err-cleartext-not-permitted-although-site-is-https) that I copied below:

Add the below line in your `application` tag:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

As shown below:

```
<application
    ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ....>
```

If you have network security config such as: `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`

No Need to set clear text traffic to true as shown above, instead use the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        ....
        ....
    </domain-config>

    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false"/>
</network-security-config>
```

Set the `cleartextTrafficPermitted` to `true`

Answer (score -2):

You can use web plugin like

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   String url = widget.url;
   return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
    child : WebviewScaffold(
      url: "https://google.com",
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      withZoom: true,
      withLocalStorage: true,
     )
   ),
 );
}
```