# How to initialise a httpserver to serve html in Flutter - net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

Tags: flutter

I'm using this as an example

https://medium.com/@segaud.kevin/facebook-oauth-login-flow-with-flutter-9adb717c9f2e

to create a http server to serve html to a webview (as a way to serve a local html file and a local javascript file that it references).  It returns net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED when it loads the webview

```
void main() async {
  HttpServer server = await HttpServer.bind("localhost", 8080);
  server.listen((HttpRequest request) async {
    request.response
      ..statusCode = 200
      ..headers.set("Content-Type", ContentType.html.mimeType)
      ..write("<html><h1>Hello</h1></html>");
  });
...
```

```
class DemoFlutterWebView3 extends StatefulWidget {
  _DemoFlutterWebViewState3 createState() => _DemoFlutterWebViewState3();
}

class _DemoFlutterWebViewState3 extends State<DemoFlutterWebView3> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        initialUrl: "http://localhost:8080/");
  }
}
```

I noticed [WebView showing ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED although site is HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707918/webview-showing-err-cleartext-not-permitted-although-site-is-https/55158284#55158284) and added the android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to the manifest file (guessing here!) but it didn't do anything.

Any ideas why the error or another way to show a html file that references a javascript file?

Comment: Actually, I just found another way to achieve this...just save the .js file to local storage and the html file and set initialUrl of the webview to the file's location...much easier!