# How to open Cordova webview using a local url for development purposes

Tags: cordova, webview, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a simple Cordova app that's loads a webview with my website url. The problem is that the site is not yet in production so i need to use the `http://example.test` instead of `https://example.com` for local development.

I tried to put the local url in the webview open method:

`cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://example.test');`

But it gives me the following error:

`Application Error. net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED (http://example.test/)`

Is the only solution to this problem to upload a pre-production site? I couldn't find any options/plugins to use a local domain in a webview.

Comment: did you try adding `www` ??

Comment: Why should I do that? My host is not www

Comment: you might want to refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707918/webview-showing-err-cleartext-not-permitted-although-site-is-https

Answer (score 0):

Since **Android 9 (Pie)**, you are not able to connect to http:// sites anymore. [Here is a blogpost about it.](https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6)

#### To fix it:

In your AndroidManifest you have to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

For example you can add this to your **config.xml**

```
<widget xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...>

<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>
    ...
</platform>
```

If you do it like this, you have to add the schema `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to your `<widget>` -tag. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56262624/4742047) for reference.