# How can I call local Firebase Functions (in Emulator) from Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I set up Cloud Functions in the local emulator. I wrote a few functions and tested them in the browser with the function emulator. Now I am trying to call these functions from my local Flutter app without deploying them. However, i cannot find a way to connect my Flutter App to the localhost API of the functions.
Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In steps:

1. Import the package:

   ```
   import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';
   ```
2. Create an instance:

   ```
   static final _functions = CloudFunctions.instance;
   ```
3. Wire it up to the emulator:

   ```
   final origin = Platform.isAndroid ? 'http://10.0.2.2:5001' : 'http://localhost:5001';
   _functions.useFunctionsEmulator(origin: origin);
   ```

Also see:

- [Error connecting to local Firebase functions emulator from Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62984527/error-connecting-to-local-firebase-functions-emulator-from-flutter-app)
- The [code for the `useFunctionsEmulator` function](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/584d0d340bae7ed3f32c09fe68aab7ddf32a4229/packages/cloud_functions/cloud_functions/lib/src/cloud_functions.dart#L45) in the Github repo.

Comment: Must be instantiated from "FirebaseFunctions", no longer from "CloudFunctions"