# Firebase Cloud Function: & Flutter: Cannot use https callable function on emulators [firebase_functions/unavailable] UNAVAILABLE

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call a HTTPS callable function using emulators, from my flutter application, but it seems not to work. After I call the function, it always takes around 5 seconds and responds with an error. It works completely normal if I deploy the function on the server instead.

Here is my function

```
exports.try = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return 1;
});
```

It is located at `us-central1`

How I started the emulators

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

How I called it from the code

```
FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.instance;
functions.useFunctionsEmulator(origin: "http://10.0.2.2:5001");
HttpsCallable callable = functions.httpsCallable('games-oneToHundred-try');
try {
  var result  = await callable();
  print(result.data);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

The error is thrown is:

```
[firebase_functions/unavailable] UNAVAILABLE
```

I modified the android manifest as suggested in [Error connecting to local Firebase functions emulator from Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62984527/error-connecting-to-local-firebase-functions-emulator-from-flutter-app) like the following:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my physical device cannot connect to localhost of my laptop.
Using Android Emulator solved my problem

Comment: Consider listening on `0.0.0.0` from your emulator is you still want to use your real device: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67973536/2619537

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS isn't available for local IP, using an emulator you must use `localhost`

```
FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator(origin: 'http://localhost:5001');
```

if you must use the IP for example on a local network with a real device, you can follow this guide
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62985709/2301161

Comment: I've already tried localhost and also did what that post suggested, as you can see from my reference link. Both of those solutions doesn't work for me