# Connect to Firebase functions emulators over local network from a Flutter app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am trying to connect to my Firebase functions emulators from my test Android device.

When I run the emulators the output is:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://localhost:4000                │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ localhost:5001 │ http://localhost:4000/functions │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at localhost:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500

Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.
```

From my Flutter app, I do the following to connect:

```
FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator(origin: 'http://192.168.1.158:5001');
```

I have added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to my AndroidManifest and a `network_security_config.xml` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62984527/error-connecting-to-local-firebase-functions-emulator-from-flutter-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59856341/okhttp-http-failed-java-net-unknownserviceexception-cleartext-communicati/59858345#59858345).

I am getting all the time the following error:

> PlatformException(firebase_functions, com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: INTERNAL, {code: unavailable, message: com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: INTERNAL}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `origin: 'http://localhost:5001'` work?

Comment: No @Dharmaraj, it's a physical device.

Comment: Then can you try `firebase serve --host 0.0.0.0` so the emulators are available over the network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, all the emulators will listen to localhost only and not your local network.

I tried replicating your issue by running my hosting emulator on the whole network and functions emulator only on localhost as in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
const firebaseConfig = {...}
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.functions().useEmulator("192.168.0.102", 5001);

var addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addMessage');
addMessage({ text: "messageText" }).then((result) => {
  // Read result of the Cloud Function.
  var sanitizedMessage = result.data.text;
});
```

I copied the sample function from the documentation and tried calling the function and as expected:

[image]

If you serve the functions using `firebase serve --only functions --host 0.0.0.0` it should make functions available for your network.

Alternatively, you can specify that in your `firebase.json` like this:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can simply start the emulators using `firebase emulators:start`.

Comment: YES.. I LIKE THAT YOU MENTIONED:  Then you can simply start the emulators using firebase emulators:start.  I was just changing the host but not restarting the emulators!!