# Can't connect firebase emulator with real device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a project which will work locally, for that I am using firebase emulator. It is working fine with emulator but not working on real device. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the configuration of my firebase.json

```
{
  "emulators": {
  "database": {
    "host":"192.168.0.124",
    "port": 1234
     },
 "ui": {
  "enabled": true
}
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to Firebase functions emulators over local network from a Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68192760/connect-to-firebase-functions-emulators-over-local-network-from-a-flutter-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

I followed two steps:

1. I did the following config:

   {
   "emulators": {
   "database": {
   "port": 9000,
   "host": "192.168.0.124"
   },
   "ui": {
   "enabled": true
   }
   },
   "database": {
   "rules": "database.rules.json"
   }
   }
2. The most important point, I was testing it on Vivo and I read somewhere that Vivo has some strange problem that it doesn't work correctly with firebase.