# Connecting public IP from angular but not from cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I have an Angular application, with an API, that connects and makes calls to a database established in a server with a public IP.

When I create the Angular project with
`ng serve`
everything works fine, I can do the calls, the server receives the requests etc
Then I wanted to export it to an apk using cordova.
When I exuecute
`ng build --prod --aot ;; cordova build browser ;; cordova run browser --port=3000` everything works fine too.
I was able to create the app and everything works fine.

My problem starts when I want to use it in a real device or an emulator.
The app is created and you can enter but the calls to the server don't work anymore.
I use `ng build --prod --aot ;; cordova build android ;; cordova run android --port=3000`

So I have to questions:

first, how could I debug this?

Second, do you have any ideas why this could happen?

Thank you

Comment: any error or warning? most probably cors issue.

Comment: Nothing, I have a login that needs to make a get to the database and it won't just login. But I'll try to search for cors errors. But maybe there are errors, I just don't know how to debug on an Android device

Comment: debug using chrome debugger

Comment: check https://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

Documentaion: 'The ng build command with the --prod meta-flag (ng build --prod) compiles with AOT by default.'

On the topic of your problem, I assume that you have forgotten to set the base href tag to be './' instead of '/'.  Try this out:

```
ng build --prod --base-href . ;; cordova run android
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I needed to allow access in the html like:

responseContext.getHeaders().add(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

More details:
[WebView showing ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED although site is HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707918/webview-showing-err-cleartext-not-permitted-although-site-is-https)