# Webview not loading url in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have this  code.

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun WebPageScreen(urlToRender: String) {
  AndroidView(factory = {
    WebView(it).apply {
      layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
      )
      webViewClient = WebViewClient()
      loadUrl("https:....") //Url to be loaded
    }
  }, update = {
    it.loadUrl("https:...") //Url to be loaded
  })
}
```

Im trying to loading this [url](http://mis.srcas.ac.in/SNRApp/dist/account/signin?returnurl=%2Fsnrapp%2F)

When i load this page it is redirecting but showing error what is the problem and how to solve this? [image: this is how it shows inside app]

Comment: your code work totally fine with https://google.com/. With your url I'm getting this error in the console: `E/chromium: [ERROR:aw_contents_client_bridge.cc(257)] No client certificate selected`. So is issue is not related to jetpack compose, I suggest you changing tags and title to something like WebView not loading url on android

Comment: Now I tried http instead of https it shows error.I have attached screenshot of error.How to resolve this issue

Comment: Have you tried looking this error code on stackoverflow?

Comment: Yes I tried most of the possible solutions

Comment: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52708032/3585796)?

Comment: Yes tried that also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webview is not working for particular url because the authorizer of that website have secured it in such a way. To Access that url in webview we need to get client certificate from the authority.

Answer (score 1):

Create this file

res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">URL</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

add this line in manifest, inside application

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

or

you can use this line in manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

if your website is not using SSL yet, you can use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) for free SSL

Comment: I tried this now but sill it shows same error

Comment: do you already change the URL to yours URL?

Comment: or you can try change networkSecurityConfig to 
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: Yes I tried I think problem in website all other sites loading only this site not loading.

Comment: Yes I replaced URL to my URL

Comment: i think the problem in http, you need to change it to https. use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) for free https

Comment: https://mis.srcas.ac.in/SNRApp/dist/account/signin?returnurl=%2Fsnrapp. With this https url i tried  it shows blank white page inside app but it works fine when I send user to browser.

Comment: Noo..It shows blank page and not showing what's in page

Comment: your problem in certificate, i got this error in log
**E/chromium: [ERROR:aw_contents_client_bridge.cc(257)] No client certificate selected** I don't know yet how to fix it

Comment: Thanks for your information . Is that SSL certificate issue?

Comment: yeah i think so, because i get that error message. i dont know how you setup your ssl, but all my url use certbot