# how to allow mailto schemes in webview flutter

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I am working on Flutter webview apps using [Flutter Webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child : const WebView(
                initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              ),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

However, if any links inside the opened web page is an app link, like: fb://profile, I will get net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

In android, I found the solution is to override shouldOverrideUrlLoading as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806191/opening-app-links-from-a-webview/51806364#51806364), but what should I do in flutter?

I'm trying the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833766/how-to-open-app-links-in-flutter-webview/58175277?noredirect=1#comment116432430_58175277).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child : const WebView(
                initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request)  {
                  if (request.url.contains("mailto:")) {
                    launch(request.url);
                    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                  }
                },
              ),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

But it is throwing errors like

> Error: Not a constant expression.
> if (request.url.contains("mailto:")) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can remove `const` keyword from `const WebView` 
Step 2: You can use `NavigationDecision.prevent`

working demo

[image]

full code

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
      child: WebView(
        initialUrl:
            'https://google.com', //'''https://www.scottseverance.us/mailto.html',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
          print(request.url);
          if (request.url.contains("mailto:")) {
            launch(request.url);
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          } else {
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          }
        },
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

Comment: The approach is working fine. But after doing the modifications, the app doesn't open on mobile. Also, the anchor tags are not working on the simulator.

Comment: I have updated full code, you can add else return NavigationDecision.navigate